# UICollectionViewCell height according to image, handle spacing between cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` consist of images, divided into two columns.

Now, cell height is calculated according to image `aspect ratio`. So, each cell’s height is different.

So, I am getting following result.

How do I manage space of top and bottom of image.

*See annotated rectangle in attached image.*

[image: Screenshot]

Edit:
See updated screenshot with *backgroundColor* of *red* for `UICollectionViewCell`.

[image]

Edit:
I achieved the output using `CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout/Swift` library. See below screenshot.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of `UICollectionViewLayout` do you use?

Comment: It is a vertical layout.

Comment: For test use a background color for each cell and share a screenshot, just so we see if that is space or is it incorrectly calculated frames...

Comment: Using system’s default layout.

Comment: Ok so add background color or even better add border with `cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0` and `cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.CGColor`

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this kind of a layout can be done with plain `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` I think you should be looking into creating your own custom `UICollectionViewLayout` to make this happen.

This is basically `Pintrest` style `UICollectionViewLayout`, so you can just follow along with some tutorials like this one:

[UICollectionView Custom Layout Tutorial: Pinterest](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2)

Or just get it from a github projet:

[PinterestLayout](https://github.com/MagicLab-team/PinterestLayout)

[CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If it answers your question you can mark it as answered by clicking the checkmark next to my answer...

Comment: Sure, I will do.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. As these libraries are indeed quite helpful to achieve desired result. I gotta achieved my desired output. See edits in my question.
Although, I was looking for some custom code/logic without using external libraries.
So, I can upvote your answer but not marked as accepted answer for now.

Comment: Look at the source code...learn from it, don't just copy it and not look how things are done, when you get to know how to make your own `UICollectionViewLayout` this kind of layout is not hard...I am glad I was able to help